# BigCommerce Edit Finishorder.php page for custom stencil theme

Tags: bigcommerce

We designed and developed a custom theme for BigCommerce using Stencil for a client.

After an order is submitted, the finishorder.php page is shown. I've attached a screenshot. We cannot find a way to modify this page. I know the checkout.php can't be edited other than targeting CSS, is the same true for finishorder.php? By default its showing base pricing. The customers' products use options to create the final price, so products appear cheaper than they actually are after a checkout. We would also like to style the buttons and modify the block listing the products that "Customers also liked" to match the rest of the theme.

[Screenshot from Finishorder.php page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU1j5.png)

Comment: Hey, I believe I just sent you an email about this. I may be able to assist.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for BigCommerce staff to enable an editable checkout (`checkout_express.html`) and thank you for your order screen (`order.html`). This will appear under Design Options > More > Template Files and be accessible through WebDAV.

Comment: Appreciate the assistance Alyss.